# Using vuex/vuejs, How to call api from external '.js' file in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am calling the api from  my external.js file and then i am calling it inside of my component using the v-for to display the required data. During this process, I am unable to call the api. Everytime i am getting error as axios defined but never used.

This is my endpoint url, Which i want to call inside of data.js file:- **https://randomuser.me/api/**

Issue when trying to call the api from external.js file in Vuejs

Code working:- https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-northcutt-wze8i?file=/src/components/data.js

**data.js**

```html
export default {
  methods: {
    mydata() {
      axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/").then((response) => this.response);
    }
  }
};
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="list in lists" :key="list.id">
      {{ list.name }}<br />{{ list.location }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { mydata } from "./data";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      lists: mydata,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to have the mock data while doing the api call or do you want to call the api?

Comment: With Mock data, i just tested weather looping is working or not. Now
From external .js file, I want to call the api only using endpoint url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should export function in simpliest way:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const mydata = () => {
  return axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/").then((response) => response);
}
```

Remember to import `axios` in your external js file because you use it there, not in component file.

Second, your API will return Promise, so you have to wait for result - you can do it by calling API in `mounted` method and filling property `list` when it will be ready.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="list in lists" :key="list.id.value">
      {{ list.name.title }} {{ list.name.first }}
      <br />{{ list.location.country }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mydata } from "./data";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      lists: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    mydata().then(r => { this.lists = r.data.results });
  }
};
</script>
```

Last but not least, an object returned from api is little different than you expect, so I have adjusted html code for real case.

Comment: What if i want to call only required fields like, {{title}} {{first}} {{country}} instead of displaying entire list?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please pay attention to html code - I've just extracted specific info on your demand.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the endpoint API using Axios like this.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user .id">
      {{ user.name }}<br />{{ user.username}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import axios from "axios";
// import { mydata } from "./data";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      // lists: mydata,
      users: []
    };
  },
  mounted () {
   axios
  .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2')
  .then(response => (this.users = response))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: My main aim is to call api from only  data.js file. Not within the component. If u can see my code https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-northcutt-wze8i?file=/src/components/data.js

i have data.js

Comment: CAN i use mounted method in .js file?

Comment: Yes, You can. But it's a difficult approach to practice. If you need to call API only from one file and reuse it. Make use of Vuex.

Comment: Yes you can use mounted in .js file.  Mounted is a function which is provided by vue js. If you want to refer more details about vue methods and life cycle please refer below link

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks -- Vue 2

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html#lifecycle-hooks -- Vue 3

Comment: If that's possible through vuex, Any idea or reference how it can be possible please.

Comment: Tutorial: https://dev.to/firstclown/how-to-query-your-api-using-vuex-in-your-vue-application-11c8


Code in action Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-api-call-from-vuex-t7zxw 

Take a look at this. If you didn't understand please let me know.